# How to configure hasMany relationship with many-to-many table

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following setup:

```
Organization (1)----(*) OrganizationArticleItemMap (*)----(1) ArticleItem
                                   (1)
                                    |
                                    |
                                    |
                                   (*)
                          ArticleItemPriceRule
```

An article item can thus belong to many organizations and an organization can have many article items. For every article item in an organization there will be multiple price rules.

The many to many relationship has been configured as such:

```
this.models.ArticleItem.belongsToMany(this.models.Organization, {
    through: this.models.OrganizationArticleItemMap,
    foreignKey: 'ArticleItemId'
    });
this.models.Organization.belongsToMany(this.models.ArticleItem, {
    through: this.models.OrganizationArticleItemMap,
    foreignKey: 'OrganizationId'
    });
```

I do not really know how I should configure ArticleItemPriceRule so that I can fetch the Price rules for all articles for a given organization.

I have tried the following :

```
this.models.ArticleItem.hasMany(this.models.OrganizationArticleItemMap, {
    foreignKey: 'ArticleItemId',
    as: 'OrganizationMaps'
});
this.models.OrganizationArticleItemMap.hasMany(this.models.ArticleItemPriceRule, {
    as: 'Prices',
    foreignKey: 'Organizations_articleitem_map_Id'
});
```

and then the following query:

```
DataAccess.dataContext.models.ArticleItem.findAll({
                include: [
                    {
                        model: DataAccess.dataContext.models.Organization,
                        where: {OrganizationId: '1'},
                        attributes: [],
                        through: {
                            attributes: []
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        model: DataAccess.dataContext.models.OrganizationArticleItemMap,
                        as: 'OrganizationMaps',
                        required: true,
                        include: [{
                            model: DataAccess.dataContext.models.ArticleItemPriceRule,
                            as: 'Prices',
                            required: false
                        }]

                    }
                ],
                where: {ArticleItemId: '1'}
            })
```

The problem with this is that the sql query that was generated included an inner join with OrganizationArticleItemMap twice.

```
SELECT `ArticleItem`.`ArticleItemId`,
       `ArticleItem`.`ArticleCategoryId`,
       `ArticleItem`.`VisibleOnOnlineBooking`,
       `OrganizationMaps`.`Organization_articleitem_map_Id` AS `OrganizationMaps.OrganizationArticleItemMapId`,
       `OrganizationMaps`.`OrganizationId` AS `OrganizationMaps.OrganizationId`,
       `OrganizationMaps`.`ArticleItemId` AS `OrganizationMaps.ArticleItemId`,
       `OrganizationMaps.Prices`.`ArticleItemPriceRuleId` AS `OrganizationMaps.Prices.ArticleItemPriceRuleId`,
       `OrganizationMaps.Prices`.`Organizations_articleitem_map_Id` AS `OrganizationMaps.Prices.Organizations_articleitem_map_Id`,
       `OrganizationMaps.Prices`.`CurrencyId` AS `OrganizationMaps.Prices.CurrencyId`,
       `OrganizationMaps.Prices`.`Price` AS `OrganizationMaps.Prices.Price`,
       `OrganizationMaps.Prices`.`ValidFrom` AS `OrganizationMaps.Prices.ValidFrom`
FROM `articleitem` AS `ArticleItem`
INNER JOIN (`organization_articleitem_map` AS `Organizations.OrganizationArticleItemMap`
            INNER JOIN `organizations` AS `Organizations` ON `Organizations`.`OrganizationId` = `Organizations.OrganizationArticleItemMap`.`OrganizationId`) ON `ArticleItem`.`ArticleItemId` = `Organizations.OrganizationArticleItemMap`.`ArticleItemId`
AND `Organizations`.`OrganizationId` = '1'
AND `Organizations`.`IsDeleted` = 0
INNER JOIN `organization_articleitem_map` AS `OrganizationMaps` ON `ArticleItem`.`ArticleItemId` = `OrganizationMaps`.`ArticleItemId`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `articleitempricerule` AS `OrganizationMaps.Prices` ON `OrganizationMaps`.`Organization_articleitem_map_Id` = `OrganizationMaps.Prices`.`Organizations_articleitem_map_Id`
AND `OrganizationMaps.Prices`.`IsDeleted` = 0
WHERE `ArticleItem`.`ArticleItemId` = '1'
  AND `ArticleItem`.`IsDeleted` = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is the response I got from the sequelize team on github:

> Sequelize doesn't know that those two relations uses the same tables.
>   You look to be doing it correctly, we just aren't smart enough to
>   infer that we could use the join table just a single time.

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/5376